# HashMap get method looks like it is returning a copy, is this right?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a program that reads a text file containing a small story word by word. Each word is checked for a label in the form "<noun>", "<verb>" or something of the like. If a label is found, it replaces that label with a random word from an ArrayList corresponding to its label using the following method:

```
private String getSubstitute(String label) {
        if (listMap.get(label) != null){
            String substitute = randomFrom(listMap.get(label));
            listMap.get(label).remove(substitute);
            return randomFrom(listMap.get(label));
        }
        if (label.equals("number")){
            return " " + myRandom.nextInt(50) + 5;
        }
    return "**UNKNOWN**";
}
```

This is working quite well, except that at each words use, it should be removed from it's corresponding list so that it cannot be re-used. I try to do this in the 4th line of code above. The HashMap `listMap<String, ArrayList>` is an instance variable, so I was under the impression that when I call
`listMap.get(label).remove(substitute)`, I would be directly accessing the ArrayList contained in listMap and removing it. However, when I run the code, sometimes I see repeats of the words that have been previously used. What am I missing here?

For a fun example, here is what was printed out in one instance:

> This is a slippery story about how a blue tiger became a  blue tiger.
>   Once upon a time, about 295 decades ago, angry,  angry pangolins
>   roamed the earth. One of them was named  Jermaine. This pangolin was
>   alone in the world. Then it  became a orange pangolin living in
>   Ecuador. This animal  loved to think and surrender. In the morning it
>   would eat a  green fig, and later eat a angry mango for a snack.

and this is the text file this story was generated from:

> This is a <adjective> story about how a <color>
>   <animal> became a <color> <animal>. Once upon a
>   time, about <number> <timeframe> ago, <adjective>,
>   <adjective> <animal>s roamed the earth. One of them was
>   named <name>. This <animal> was alone in the world. Then
>   it became a <color> <animal> living in <country>.
>   This animal loved to <verb> and <verb>. In the morning it
>   would eat a <color> <fruit>, and later eat a
>   <adjective> <fruit> for a snack.

Comment: Shouldn't you be returning substitute?

Comment: In summary:  A method call is *not* a variable.  A method call is an *operation.*  If you call make a method call four times, you are *performing that operation* four times.  Your method should call `listMap.get(label)` *only once.*  It should call `randomFrom` *only once.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you definitely remove the one assigned to `substitute`.  But but you don't return that one.   You return another random one.  So you didn't remove the one you returned.

It should be.

```
    private String getSubstitute(String label) {
        if (listMap.get(label) != null){
            String substitute = randomFrom(listMap.get(label));
            listMap.get(label).remove(substitute);
            return substitute;
        }
        if (label.equals("number")){
            return " " + myRandom.nextInt(50) + 5;
        }
        return "**UNKNOWN**";
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't remove what getSubstitute returns. You are returning next random word that You generated at the end:

`return randomFrom(listMap.get(label));`

Comment: Not correct. The OP does remove substitute.  But that is not the one returning.

Comment: Here: 
`String substitute = randomFrom(listMap.get(label));`
Op gets random substitute. Next:
`listMap.get(label).remove(substitute);`
Op removes substitute from list. Next:
`return randomFrom(listMap.get(label));`

Op returns other word.

Comment: Which is what I said.  The op removed the one assigned to 'substitute' but returns a different word.

Comment: So what is not clear in my answer?

EDIT

ok i wrote it more clear i think

Answer (score 0):

At line no : 5

```
return substitute;
```

instead of

```
return randomFrom(listMap.get(label));
```